# how much RAM my laptop can support

Tags: memory

I've purchased Dell Inspiron15 3558 which specs are:

Intel Core i3 5005U @ 2.00GHz.

4.00GB Single-Channel DDR3 @ 798MHz. (2 slots, 1 used)

Intel HD Graphics 5500

1 TB HDD.

how much RAM I can extend in it.
I checked on Crucial.com and Crucial System Scanner both says max 16 GB,
but Kingston.com says max 8GB and now I'm confused which one is true,
 because I want to extend it to 12GB (8GB+4GB).
and If I'll buy one 8GB from local market or Online and if it'll not work they will replace it but not return and refund, so I can't purchase until i'm sure.

is there any other way to find out actual compatibility ??
 can anyone help??

Answer (score 1):

According to Dell's [website](http://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/productdetails/inspiron-15-3558-laptop), the max is 8GB.